# Google Photos: Add separator / divider to album

Tags: google-photos

How do I add separators / dividers / nested albums to a Google Photos album?
Apparently this must be possible, I just wonder how?

Example: 
https://photos.google.com/share/AF1QipNi8VN2pw2Ya_xCV8eFgzEZmiXDy1-GwhXbqFtvXoH3HypF10as9puV8FdoVZpOZA?key=WkZjQTIxQTM5a01oZkNUYTE2ZllKTVJKZk1CMTR3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Google Photos album and select the three ellipses (top right) and select "Edit Album". Select the "Tt" for Add Text. This will add a text separator to your album. You can drag and move it around where you like. You can add multiple separators to an album.